# Identity theorem with third order derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to find all holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ such that

$n^4\,f^{(3)}(\frac{1}{n})+1=0$, for all integer $n \ge 1$

My solution so far is the following:

Let $g(z)=-z^4$. The function $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ (as a polynomial) and satisfies

$g(\frac{1}{n})=-\frac{1}{n^4}=f^{(3)}(\frac{1}{n}),\,\forall n \ge 1$.

So, the functions $f^{(3)}$ and $g$ coincide on the set $U=\{\frac{1}{n};n\ge1\}$ which contains an accumulation point at $0$. Therefore, by the Identity theorem, $f^{(3)}\equiv g$ on $U$, so that $f^{(3)}(z)=-z^4$.

Successive integrations then give:

$f^{\prime\prime}(z)=-\frac{1}{5}z^5+a$, $f^{\prime}(z)=-\frac{1}{30}z^6+a\,z+b$ and finally 
$f(z)=-\frac{1}{210}z^7+\frac{1}{2}a\,z^2+b\,z+c$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Do you think that solution is correct? I was also looking for a way to evaluate the constants $a,b$ and $c$.

Many thanks for your advice.

Comment: Overall your argument is correct, I have a comment only, I understand that $n$ a natural number, so that $U$ is not open.

Comment: @Diego Fonseca Yes you are right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks to all, I edited the original question and fixed the mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct apart from a typo, and the set $U$
is not open (and doesn't need to be), so

> the functions $f$ and $g$ coincide on the open set $U =  \ldots $

should be

> the functions $f^{(3)}$ and $g$ coincide on the set $U = \ldots$

The functions
$$f(z)=-\frac{1}{210}z^7+\frac{1}{2}a\,z^2+b\,z+c$$
satisfy the given condition for arbitrary $a, b, c \in \Bbb C$,
so there is no way to determine them further.

Comment: Yes you are indeed correct about $U$. Many thanks for your help.